# Google AMP failing, but validator says its Ok

Tags: amp-html

From some time now, when I visit some pages of my blog via mobile, the ones that **are AMP enabled** are failing, here is an example for the post [Scala Category Theory - Composition](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/scala-category-theory-composition/):

[image: amp fail]

If I click **debug original page**, it goes to the amp validator web. At the beginning it show errors, but immediately reloads and says the validation test passes. You can see it yourself in [the debug link](https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Felbauldelprogramador.com%2Fen%2Fscala-category-theory-composition%2F)

I do not know what is going on, since **Google Web Master tools** show all amps pages are valid.

Is anyone having the same issue? It has been working since I've implemented Google AMP, but now I do not know what has happened.

## Update

If I click in *show errors* in the Image above I get:

```
Error in line 1, column 0: The document is too complex
```

But then, why it reloads automatically and validate?

## Update II

I am trying to reduce the page complexity, I'll wait a couple of days until google re indexes the website and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I've tried browsing your [website](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/scala-category-theory-composition/) and it looks good. You may want to check this [blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/how-to-avoid-common-mistakes-when-publishing-accelerated-mobile-pages-9ea61abf530f) to avoid the common mistakes when publishing Accelerated Mobile Pages.

Comment: @abielita It seems to be working now. Maybe it is due to Update II

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems reducing page complexity solved the issue.

Im posting this as an answer to mark it as solved.